# Bokeh Graph for Resampled, Hierarchical, Categorical+Time Data

Tags: python, dataframe, bokeh, hierarchical-data

I know that I'm getting close on this, but I just can't get bokeh to do what I'm looking for. I need to resample time data into 15 minute intervals, then group it by hierarchical, categorical types and graph the result across the time groups. Would appreciate any help.

I've got data that look like this:

```
    basket_id   food_type               classified_time             dipped_time                 slot_number
0   185261      CHICKEN FILLETS         2019-07-07 11:38:23.153858  2019-07-07 11:38:40.271070  8
1   185263      CHICKEN FILLETS         2019-07-07 11:38:25.831668  2019-07-07 11:38:53.265553  4
2   185273      CRISPY CHICKEN TENDERS  2019-07-07 11:39:26.184932  2019-07-07 11:39:58.164302  5
3   185276      CRISPY CHICKEN TENDERS  2019-07-07 11:39:30.178273  2019-07-07 11:39:46.076617  1
...
```

I can resample this data so that I get this result, which looks very much like it is on the right track:

```
agg_15m = df[['dipped_time', 'food_type']] \
            .set_index('dipped_time', 'food_type') \
            .groupby('food_type') \
            .resample('15Min') \
            .agg({'food_type': 'count'}) \
            .rename(columns={'food_type':'COUNT'}) \
            .reset_index()
display(agg_15m)
```

[image: resampled data]

I can then use groupby to get what I think is the right structure:

```
group = agg_15m.groupby(['dipped_time', 'food_type'])
display(group.sum())
```

[image: grouped by time and food type]

This alone took quite a bit of figuring in dataframes, as I'm not really familiar with the concepts of working with multi-indexed data.

Now the fun part, trying to get Bokeh to do something with this data. [This instruction from bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#pandas) seems to give the right direction; however, it is using only a single groupby. [This instruction from bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#pandas) gives some direction for hierarchical categorical data, but the example is done using only literals.

So here's what I've tried.

```
    p = figure(
        title="Baskets Cooked per 15min",
        y_axis_label="Count",
        plot_width=plot_width,
        plot_height=plot_height,
        toolbar_location=toolbar_loc,
    )
    p.vbar(x='dipped_time_food_type', top='COUNT', width=1e3*60*15, source=self.group.sum() )
```

This gives an empty graph
[image: empty graph]

If I try putting the group object into the x_range, [as per these instructions](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#pandas),

```
self.p = figure(
            title="Baskets Cooked per 15min",
            y_axis_label="Count",
            plot_width=plot_width,
            plot_height=plot_height,
            toolbar_location=toolbar_loc,
            x_range=group
        )
```

I get the following error while just setting up the figure, even though this seems to be [the format explained here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#mixed-factors):

```
ValueError: expected an element of either Seq(String), Seq(Tuple(String, String)) or Seq(Tuple(String, String, String)), got [(Timestamp('2019-07-07 11:30:00'), 'CHICKEN FILLETS'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 11:30:00'), 'CRISPY CHICKEN TENDERS'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 11:30:00'), 'POPCORN CHICKEN'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 11:30:00'), 'POTATO FRIES'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 11:45:00'), 'CHICKEN FILLETS'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 11:45:00'), 'CRISPY CHICKEN TENDERS'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 11:45:00'), 'POPCORN CHICKEN'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 11:45:00'), 'POTATO FRIES'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 12:00:00'), 'CHICKEN FILLETS'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 12:00:00'), 'CRISPY CHICKEN TENDERS'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 12:00:00'), 'POPCORN CHICKEN'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 12:00:00'), 'POTATO FRIES'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 12:15:00'), 'CHICKEN FILLETS'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 12:15:00'), 'CRISPY CHICKEN TENDERS'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 12:15:00'), 'POPCORN CHICKEN'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 12:15:00'), 'POTATO FRIES'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 12:30:00'), 'CHICKEN FILLETS'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 12:30:00'), 'CRISPY CHICKEN TENDERS'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 12:30:00'), 'POPCORN CHICKEN'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 12:30:00'), 'POTATO FRIES'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 12:45:00'), 'CRISPY CHICKEN TENDERS'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 12:45:00'), 'POPCORN CHICKEN'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 12:45:00'), 'POTATO FRIES'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 13:00:00'), 'CRISPY CHICKEN TENDERS'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 13:00:00'), 'POTATO FRIES'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 13:15:00'), 'CRISPY CHICKEN TENDERS'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 13:15:00'), 'POTATO FRIES'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 13:30:00'), 'CRISPY CHICKEN TENDERS'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 13:30:00'), 'POTATO FRIES'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 13:45:00'), 'POTATO FRIES'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 14:00:00'), 'POTATO FRIES'), (Timestamp('2019-07-07 14:15:00'), 'POTATO FRIES')]
```

I've tried a couple other things as well, but this seems to be the closest I've gotten. Would love any insight on the structure of the dataframe, or any other stupid bug I'm missing.

Thanks for the help!

**Edit**
So I noticed that that last error wasn't about the data structure, it was about the data types. So I converted the datetimes into strings:

```
agg_15m = df[['dipped_time', 'food_type']] \
                .set_index('dipped_time', 'food_type') \
                .groupby('food_type') \
                .resample('15Min') \
                .agg({'food_type': 'count'}) \
                .rename(columns={'food_type':'COUNT'}) \
                .reset_index()
agg_15m['dipped_time'] = agg_15m['dipped_time'].to_string()
self.group = agg_15m.groupby(['dipped_time', 'food_type'])
self.p = figure(
            title="Baskets Cooked per 15min",
            y_axis_label="Count",
            plot_width=plot_width,
            plot_height=plot_height,
            toolbar_location=toolbar_loc,
            x_range=self.group
        )
self.p.vbar(x='dipped_time_food_type', top='COUNT_std', width=1, source=ColumnDataSource(self.group))
```

This is now giving me a fairly ugly graph that doesn't seem to represent the underlying data.

[image: ugly graph]

I'm trying to get to something a bit more like this:
[image: pretty graph]

**EDIT**

Last version of string conversion was incorrect. Updated to

```
agg_15m = df[['dipped_time', 'food_type']] \
                .set_index('dipped_time', 'food_type') \
                .groupby('food_type') \
                .resample('15Min') \
                .agg({'food_type': 'count'}) \
                .rename(columns={'food_type':'COUNT'}) \
                .reset_index()
agg_15m['dipped_time'] = agg_15m['dipped_time'].astype(str)
self.group = agg_15m.groupby(['dipped_time', 'food_type'])
self.p = figure(
            title="Baskets Cooked per 15min",
            y_axis_label="Count",
            plot_width=plot_width,
            plot_height=plot_height,
            toolbar_location=toolbar_loc,
            x_range=self.group
        )
self.p.vbar(x='dipped_time_food_type', top='COUNT_std', width=1, source=ColumnDataSource(self.group))
```

This gives the correct data, but now the graph is empty with some artifacts on the corner. 
[image: empty graph with artifacts in corner]

**EDIT**

I couldn't get it working, so I went for the manual method. This code works:

```
    df['dipped_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dipped_time'], errors='coerce') #convert to datetime so we can resample
    #group by food and resample to 15min intervals
    agg_15m = df[['dipped_time', 'food_type']] \
                .set_index('dipped_time', 'food_type') \
                .groupby('food_type') \
                .resample('15Min') \
                .agg({'food_type': 'count'}) \
                .rename(columns={'food_type':'COUNT'}) \
                .reset_index()
    agg_15m['dipped_time'] = agg_15m['dipped_time'].astype(str)
    plot_width  = 800
    plot_height = 600
    toolbar_loc = 'above'

    self.p = figure(
            title="Baskets Cooked per 15min",
            y_axis_label="Count",
            plot_width=plot_width,
            plot_height=plot_height,
            toolbar_location=toolbar_loc,
            x_range=sorted(self.agg_15m.dipped_time.unique())
        )
    self.food_types = self.agg_15m.food_type.unique()
    self.data_source = dict(
            x=sorted(self.agg_15m.dipped_time.unique())
        )
    df = self.agg_15m
    for food_type in self.food_types:
            arr = []
            for time in sorted(self.agg_15m.dipped_time.unique()):
                if df.loc[(df["dipped_time"]==time) & (df["food_type"]==food_type), "COUNT"].empty:
                    arr.append(0)
                else:
                    arr.append(df.loc[(df["dipped_time"]==time) & (df["food_type"]==food_type), "COUNT"].values[0])
            self.data_source[food_type] = arr

    fill_colors=[
            Spectral5[i]
            for i in range(len(self.food_types))]

    self.p.vbar_stack(self.food_types, \
                          x='x', \
                          width=0.9, alpha=0.5, \
                          source=ColumnDataSource(self.data_source), \
                          fill_color=fill_colors,
                          legend=[value(x) for x in self.food_types])
```

[image: successful graph]

Still open to more idiomatic solutions.

Comment: Can you provide a small sample dataset here or in a gist?

Comment: @bigreddot https://gist.github.com/kenxle/f6386277d75bf01a701d586e49d27976

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to plot `COUNT_std` as the top of the bars, but if you actually look at the data in the `ColumnDataSource`, you can see it is nothing but NaN values:

```
 'COUNT_std': array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]),
```

And indeed, if you go back to the group, and look at the output of `group.describe()` you can see that the NaNs come from there:

```
In [40]: group.describe()
Out[40]:
                                           COUNT
                                           count mean std  min  25%  50%  75%  max
dipped_time         food_type
2019-07-07 12:30:00 POTATO FRIES             1.0  5.0 NaN  5.0  5.0  5.0  5.0  5.0
2019-07-07 12:45:00 CRISPY CHICKEN TENDERS   1.0  3.0 NaN  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
                    POPCORN CHICKEN          1.0  3.0 NaN  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
                    POTATO FRIES             1.0  4.0 NaN  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0
2019-07-07 13:00:00 CRISPY CHICKEN TENDERS   1.0  6.0 NaN  6.0  6.0  6.0  6.0  6.0
                    POTATO FRIES             1.0  3.0 NaN  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
2019-07-07 13:15:00 CRISPY CHICKEN TENDERS   1.0  0.0 NaN  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
                    POTATO FRIES             1.0  5.0 NaN  5.0  5.0  5.0  5.0  5.0
2019-07-07 13:30:00 CRISPY CHICKEN TENDERS   1.0  6.0 NaN  6.0  6.0  6.0  6.0  6.0
                    POTATO FRIES             1.0  1.0 NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2019-07-07 13:45:00 POTATO FRIES             1.0  6.0 NaN  6.0  6.0  6.0  6.0  6.0
2019-07-07 14:00:00 POTATO FRIES             1.0  0.0 NaN  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2019-07-07 14:15:00 POTATO FRIES             1.0  3.0 NaN  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
```

I'm not sure offhand why that column ends up full of NaNs, but this is the immediate cause of the issues with the last plot. If instead you use a column with valid numerical values, e.g. `COUNT_max`:

```
p.vbar(x='dipped_time_food_type', top='COUNT_max', width=0.9, source=group)
```

Then you can see a plot like the one you are after, modulo any visual styling:

[image]

Note that I made the bar width 0.9 so there is actually space between them.

Comment: Good call. I used COUNT_std because an error suggested it as a column name and I was moving too fast. Didn't know what it was. I assume it's NaN because you can't have a standard dev with only one value in each bucket.

Comment: I think I'm going to go with the stacked bars anyway, because I need to make the x-axis an actual timeline so that any gaps will show up. Categorical axis will just ignore any 15min gaps, which are important for me to highlight here. Thanks for the help in catching that bug! As always, frustrating that it was that simple.

Comment: Actually, I made the updates just to check, and it just made the graph disappear entirely. I'm sure it's something local to my machine, but weird that there's no error and no graph. Thanks again for the help.